# How to animate the bottom border of a container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, mobile

I wanted to create something very similar to the TabBar animation. When you have two tabs and you click on the one to the right, the bottom border is animated like it was transitioning from one container (tab) to the other. Can I do that animation with the borders of a container?

Here is the code for my container:

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.blueAccent),
    ),
  ),
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      'Container',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        fontSize: 17.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by Using a `AnimatedContainer` instead of the `Container`:

```
AnimatedContainer(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.blueAccent),
    ),
  ),
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      'Container',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        fontSize: 17.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Hope that helps if anyone needs it.